# Is there a software that can graph parametric equations where x and y are defined implicitly?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

For example, I am working on an exercise from a Calculus book that asks to find the slope of $x=f(t), y=g(t)$ at $t=2$, where

$$
\begin{align}
x^2-2tx+2t^2&=4\\
2y^3-3t^2&=4
\end{align}
$$

I have already worked out the solution and found that $dy/dx|_{t=2}=0$, but I was interested in plotting the graph just for kicks and giggles.  I don't think my TI Nspire can do it, or at least I don't know how. Could I use Octave or WolframAlpha somehow?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geogebra is your friend in this case.

Create a slider for values of $t$.

Create a list of the possible values of $x$: `listofx=Solutions(x^(2)-2 t x+2 t^(2)=4)`

Create a list of the possible values of $y$: `listofy=Solutions(2 y^(3)-3 t^(2)=4)`

Geogebra will give you as many values of $x$ and $y$ as the equations will yield and it's happy with implicit equations.

Then turn those coordinates into points using the "Element" command.

`A=(Element(listofx,1),Element(listofy,1))`

`B=(Element(listofx,2),Element(listofy,1))`

Create a trace of the points A and B as you adjust $t$

Teaching a lesson now, but will post image later.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  I was able to get the graph (looks like a sideways figure 8 or an infinity symbol).  And the graph also confirmed my answer.